# How to import only some of csv into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, csv, google-sheets-import-csv

I'm trying to auto-import [this huge csv file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties-2022.csv) into Google Sheets, but when I use the `importdata` function, it tells me "Resource at URL contents exceeded maximum size." I'd like it to auto-update daily. I just want data for California, and am wondering of there's a straightforward way to query that.

Comment: While a link to an external file might be helpful, questions should be self-contained. You should describe the file directly in the question body, i.e, mention the number of lines and columns.

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult to put California data in a sheet, just copy/paste the California lines and you will get [this file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gB29sINWtb7aFoavc4P3y1dVIISvcbQrVuf4uCFswk0/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thank you for this response, Daniele. I'd actually like to set it up so it auto-updates on a daily basis. Any thoughts on how to set that up?

Comment: Unfortunately you will not be able to automate it through a google sheet, due to its limitation on the number of characters / lines that can be imported, which does not even allow you to divide the csv into several parts: I believe that your only option is to use a site/program that splits the csv